# Convert curl request to the python request

Tags: python, curl, request

Give me please an expamle of python request of this curl request

```
curl -X POST "https://api.skinbaron.de/Search" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "content-type: application/json" -d "{  \"apikey\": \"string\",  \"appid\": 0,  \"search_item\": \"string\",  \"min\": 0,  \"max\": 111,  \"after_saleid\": \"string\",  \"items_per_page\": 0}"
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/requests/

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [uncurl](https://github.com/spulec/uncurl) project. Using python3, I was able to parse your curl request to its corresponding pythonic version:

```
requests.post("https://api.skinbaron.de/Search",
    data='{  apikey: string,  appid: 0,  search_item: string,  min: 0,  max: 111,  after_saleid: string,  items_per_page: 0}',
    headers={
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    cookies={},
)
```

Comment: Thats it. Thank you